# Left Join when > 0 rows but doesn't match where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have a query where if there are no matching join in the table it show zero which is what I want.  However, if there are matching rows but they don't match the rows in the where clause, I don't get a zero I get nothing.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    PUEvents PUE1
OUTER APPLY (
              SELECT    day
              FROM      Day_Map
              WHERE     Date = '2014-04-12'
            ) D1
OUTER APPLY (
              SELECT    date
              FROM      Day_Map
              WHERE     Day = D1.Day AND
                        Year = '2013' AND
                        MapID > 976
            ) D2
LEFT JOIN PUConsumerData PUC ON PUC.EventID = PUE1.EventID
WHERE   PUE1.EventID > 4958 AND
        PUE1.EventId < 5023 AND
        PUE1.TourID = 353 AND
        (
          CONVERT(DATE, PUC.PictureTakenDate) = '2014-04-12' OR
          PUC.PictureTakenDate IS NULL
        ) AND
        (
          PUC.FirstName <> 'ZOOM' OR
          FirstName IS NULL
        )
ORDER BY PUE1.Name
```

So for row 51, there are rows in the database with that eventid but not for the date range so I don't get the event data.  I need the event data just the fact there's no matching consumer data.

Comment: As soon as you reference PUC in the where clause, you turn the outer join into an inner join. Move those clauses to the ON clause.

Comment: Please set up some sample data on sqlfiddle, and show expected results. Word problems suck.

Answer (score 0):

[aaron-betrand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61305/aaron-bertrand) was right if I move the conditions in the WHERE clause up to the JOIN it worked fine.  Simple